# How to edit cell value of lightning data table programtically

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, bulk

I have a lightning data table with a inline editable field. It working perfect as expected when I do manual edit and save. What I need in addition to the existing behaviour is, I need to edit the value of entire column onButton click. Then It will enable bulk update for the user.

I was researching for this everywhere on the internet and unable to find a solution. If anyone has come through similar situation and has found a solution, I appreciate your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a different datatable with checkboxes displayed attribute depending on a button on the component.

To mass edit your rows, you can use checkboxes. The checkbox at the first low level if clicked, will select all remaining rows.

Attribute I mention is `hideCheckboxColumn`, here's a sample code to get the selected row below.

```js
    handleClickAdd() {

        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        let selectedIdsArray = [];

        for (const element of selected) {
            //console.log('elementid', element.Id);
            selectedIdsArray.push(element.Id);
        }
```

Comment: I can get selected-rows or select rows programmatically. My table already has check-boxes. What I need to do is change cell value on button click.